# Can I use Notifications in Android 2.2 with newest SDK version?

Tags: android, compatibility

Class NotificationCompatBase used by NotificationCompat.Builder requires API 9.

And if I use it, I have error:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.app.Notification.fullScreenIntent`

Is there another way to do it or its impossible?

Update:

Test notification building code:

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setTicker("this is ticker text")
                    .setContentTitle( "Title" )
                    .setContentText( "Text" )
                    .setFullScreenIntent( pendingIntent, true )
                    .setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher )
                    .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
                    .getNotification();
```

Comment: Post the code so that we can get more information, without the code, it is very difficult to provide more information.

Comment: "Class NotificationCompatBase used by NotificationCompat.Builder requires API 9" -- `26.0.0` and higher versions of the support library requires API Level 14. Older versions of the support library should work back to API Level 4. What version are you using?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I use version 25.0.0 and this doesn't work. If I try older version, i have warn "This support library should not use a different version (22) than the compileSdkVersion (25)" Is it normal?

Comment: Sync gradle with this warn, build app and it works. Still dont know normal it or not, but thank you for help.